# Apache/PHP Undefined function - occurs sometimes - fix by apache restart

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm facing a really strange problem

My website sometimes starting to serve errors like

```
2018/09/25 09:13:33 [error] [php] Call to undefined function @=Q<C6>+V(). File: /var/www/xxxx/MainModule.php. Line: 491
```

But in the file is no error at all - The problem exists until I restart or reload apache. Then it's fine for a few hours and suddenly it happens again.
The error is always in the same file, but with different "wrong" function names

Unfortunately I cannot provide enough information to reproduce the problem, but I hope you have some ideas about what can be the cause for such behaviour.

I already thought about APC, so I set a filter in the config so this file is not cached by apc. But it had no positive effect

```
  apc.filters="-/var/www/xxxx/MainModule.php"
```

Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

PHP Version 5.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Reason is APC but my inital APC filter was wrong (it should be a regex)

So we changed it to:

```
 apc.filters="-.*MainModule\.php"
```

Now the error **does not** occure anymore, but the main reason is not fixed atm.

We also recognized segmentation faults in the apache error log

```
 [notice] child pid 29776 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

and the inital error just appear directly after these errors.

We continue to investigate in these error